# Is there an alternative to select()/epoll() for Windows that works with generic file descriptors and not only with sockets?

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, events

I am trying to solve the following problem on Windows.

Given a set of file descriptors (not necessarily sockets), wait until an event is fired on one of them.

Initially I thought to use a call to `select()`, but I have discovered that the behavior is slightly different from POSIX.

In fact, according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx), the `select()` in Windows only works with sockets and not with generic file descriptors.

There are other functions in the documentation, but they all have the same problem.

Would you recommend any alternative function?
Ideally, I would really like something faster than `select()` like `epoll()`, which is also only available on Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you may be looking for [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx), or for a complete portable solution: [libuv](http://libuv.org/)

Comment: What kind of events are you talking about getting fired?

Comment: There isn't anything directly analogous to select/epoll for general I/O.  Windows uses a different approach, you have to issue the I/O and wait for an event indicating it is complete, rather than waiting for an event indicating the handle is ready and then issuing the I/O.  (`select` only exists for sockets because it was part of the de-facto standard.)